# How do I type compound characters using Telugu keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I would like to know how to type [image] (*Namaste*) on Telugu keyboard.

I tried "Telugu(kaGapa phonetic)" keyboard:
[image] but I can only type upto this [image], unable to add the "tha vatthu" to the last letter. The "tha vatthu" is on <kbd><</kbd> but it doesn't produce that telugu character when typed.

On another Telugu keyboard, there is no such "tha vatthu" at all:
[image]

Are these keyboards capable of typing all the Telugu characters or am I missing something?

Edit: Letter on <kbd><</kbd> is not really the required letter to complete the "namaste" word. But I am leaving the details like this because the answer is still valid for the keys that have more than two characters.

Comment: See if this Unicode string analysis is useful: http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/?q=%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%A4%E0%B1%87 You'll have to enter characters in order as listed here from top to bottom.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks that helped. Certainly a tricky one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is "నమస్తే" (from Google Translate, English → Telugu: "Namaste"). [Unicode string analysis](http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/?q=%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%A4%E0%B1%87) shows that it contains the following characters in order

> **న**  (U+0C28)
>   **మ**   (U+0C2E)
>   **స**   (U+0C38)
>   **్**‌‌‌‌‌   (U+0C4D)
>   **త**   (U+0C24)
>   **ే** (U+0C47)

So you'll just have to enter these characters in the right order.

Also you said you found the special character on <kbd><</kbd> (in the first screenshot), but it didn't work. I noticed the special character assigned to <kbd><</kbd> is placed at the bottom right. So you'll have to press the **Level3** selection key (<kbd>alt gr</kbd> or *right alt*) along with it (that is if you press right <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> it will produce the desired result).

Comment: I like the phonetic keyboard better as the sound matches with the sound of English letters which makes typing easier. But unable to type some letters like `అ  ఇ `, that is, keys that have more than two letters. But can do on the other keyboard. Any idea how or any documentation on how to use these phonetic keyboard?

Comment: Not really an elegant solution, but I think Google translate has a smart phonetic input option for almost all (if not all) languages. You can type in there and copy-paste to other places.

Comment: Also you might want to check out [Google Input Tools](https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/). It has a [Chrome extension](https://www.google.com/inputtools/chrome/) too. Sadly no offline app for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the KaGaPa phonetic keyboard, you can initiate the vatthu by using "pollu" character obtained by clicking on f

So, the sequence for obtaining నమస్తే is like

n-> m-> s ->f ->t -> E

f is useful for forming any such dwithwakshara/samyukthakshara.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thanks for posting an answer. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. Also, formatting your answers properly will help others to understand your answer better and looks nice. See [How to format](/help/formatting) and [answer]. Thanks :)